# Need powershell script to enable diagnostic logging for Storage account and Key vault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-diagnostics

I'm using below script to create a storage account, Key Vault and ADF. I would also like to enable diagnostic logging on both Storage account and Key Vault. Script runs fine and creates the resources however it does not enable the diagnostic logs for KV and Storage account. Would appreciate if you can help.

```
$subscription="Azure subscription 1"
$rgName = "Test"
$location = "eastus"
$storageaccountName = "tempaccountlogs"
$adfName = "tempdpadf"
$department = "Testtemp"
$kvname = "kvnamAkbt"

$sa = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AccountName $storageaccountName -Location $location -SkuName Standard_LRS -Kind BlobStorage -AccessTier Hot -Tag @{department=$department}
$DataFactory = Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name $adfName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Tag @{chargecode=$chargeCode;department=$department;environment=$environment;project=$project}
$kv = New-AzKeyVault -VaultName $kvname -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location


set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -Enabled $true -Categories AuditEvent
set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays 90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `-WorkspaceId` parameter in the cmd. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-4.1.0#parameters).

My example which runs successfully:

```
set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -Enabled $true -Category AuditEvent -WorkspaceId {resource id of the Log Analytics workspace}
```

For how to create a Log Analytics workspace, please refer to [Create workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powershell-workspace-configuration#create-workspace).

---

**Update:**

For how to enable diagnostic logs for ADF, please refer to this sample:

```
$ws = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "testLAW" -ResourceGroupName "test"
$DataFactory = Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name "testADF" -Location "WestUS"
set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $DataFactory.DataFactoryId  -Enabled $true -WorkspaceId $ws.ResourceId
```

Comment: Thanks Allen for the help !! I got the script working and now I'm able to enable the diagnostic logs for both storage and KV. Any suggestion on how to enable the diagnostics for ADF too. again thanks !!

Comment: @AkbarMohammed What error did you encounter when enabling the diagnostics for ADF?

Comment: I don't have the script to enable diagnostic logs for ADF. Would appreciate if you can share it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is that it gives error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Categories'.

You are using "Categories" parameter instead of "Category". If you check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-4.1.0#parameters) correct parameter is `-Category`, use this as shown below:

```
set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -Enabled $true -Category AuditEvent
set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $kv.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $sa.Id -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays 90
```

To enable logging for storage account, Please look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet#enable-storage-logging-using-powershell).

Comment: Thanks Jagrati !! could you please suggest on how to enable the diagnostics for ADF.

Comment: Can you please help here?

Answer (score 1):

```
$diagname = "storage logs"
    
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Import-Module -Name Az
    
Import-Csv "$home\azuresubscription.csv" |`
ForEach-Object{
        
    #CentralLogAnalytics
    $workspaceid = "your central logging resource id - exact object"
    Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $_.Name
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Select-Object Id

    foreach ($stor in $storageAccounts)
    {
        Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $diagname -ResourceId $stor.Id -WorkspaceId $workspaceid -Enabled $true
    
        $blobid = -join($stor.id,"/blobServices/default")
        $fileid = -join($stor.id, "/fileServices/default")
        $queueid = -join($stor.id, "/queueServices/default")
        $tableid = -join($stor.id, "/tableServices/default")
    
        $resourcetypeid = @($blobid, $fileid, $queueid, $tableid)
        foreach ($item in $resourcetypeid)
        {
            Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $diagname -ResourceId $item -WorkspaceId $workspaceid -Enabled $true 
        }        
    }
}
```

**Prerequisite:**
The script expects a list of azure subscription in a CSV file. Putting in CSV is best to easy test in NonProd subscriptions. An object of the subscriptions can also be provided here.

**Functionality:**
This will enable the metrics for blob, queue, file, and table and at the parent level as well.